# Почему функция раскрытия списка на вебстранице не срабатывает?

Tags: javascript, html

Существует страница со следующим содержимым:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function down(info) {
            var a = document.getElementById(info);
            if ( a.style.display === 'none' )
                a.style.display = 'block';
            else
            if ( a.style.display === 'block' )
                a.style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="droplink">
1 Animals
<a class="socialbutton" onclick='down('Animals');this.innerHTML=="[+]" ? this.innerHTML="[-]" : this.innerHTML="[+]"'>[+]</a>
<ul id="Animals" style="display:none">
<li class=str>    tiger</li>
<li class=str>    dog</li>
<li class=str>    cat</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="droplink">
2 Humans
<a class="socialbutton" onclick='down('Humans');this.innerHTML=="[+]" ? this.innerHTML="[-]" : this.innerHTML="[+]"'>[+]</a>
<ul id="Humans" style="display:none">
<li class=str>    russians</li>
<li class=str>    germans</li>
<li class=str>    americans</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="droplink">
3 Planes
<a class="socialbutton" onclick='down('Planes');this.innerHTML=="[+]" ? this.innerHTML="[-]" : this.innerHTML="[+]"'>[+]</a>
<ul id="Planes" style="display:none">
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Выглядит это все следующим образом:

```
1 Animals [+]
2 Humans [+]
3 Planes [+]
```

Функция раскрытия списка представлена выше (down()).
Ожидаемое мной поведение: при нажатии на плюс выскочит содержимое. Сама иконка плюса поменяется на минус, при нажатии на который список уберется обратно. И так для каждого плюса в отдельности.

Я в javascript человек новый, поэтому не понимаю, почему при нажатии на плюс не раскрывается список?

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена следующим образом:
Произошел конфликт внутри строки:

```
...onclick='down('Humans');this.innerHTML=="[+]" ?...
```

т.е. одинарные кавычки по краям Humans ломали структуру атрибута onclick. Задача решилась заменой этих кавычек на двойные.